# Get number present after a particular pattern of a matching string in Python

Tags: python, regex, string-matching

I want to get all the matching numbers(only numbers example '0012--22') or numbers which contain some text (example 'RF332') corresponding to it which matches with a list of strings provided("my_list" in the code). The format in which the text with number will be present is like separated by a space or two. Providing sample input file for reference.

This is the input file:

```
$cat input_file
some text before Expedien: 1-21-212-16-26 some random text
Reference RE9833 of all sentences.
abc
123
456
something blah blah Ref.: 
tramite  1234567
Ref.:
some junk Expedien N° 18-00777 # some new content
some text Expedien N°18-0022995 # some garbled content
```

The script till now is attached below: It is currently only identifying one element which is {'tramite': '1234567'}

```
import re
import glob
import os

my_list = ['Ref.:', 'Reference', 'tramite', 'Expediente', 'Expediente No', 'Expedien N°', 'Exp.No', 'Expedien']

#open the file as input
with open('garb.txt','r') as infile:
  res = dict()
  for line in infile:  
    elems = re.split('(?::)?\s+', line)
    #print(elems)
    if len(elems) >= 2 :
      contains = False
      tmp = ''
      for elem in elems:  
        if contains:
          res.update({tmp : elem})
          print(res)
          contains = False
          break
        if elem in my_list:
          contains = True
          tmp = elem
  #print(res)
```

This is the expected output:

Sample output:

```
{'Expedien N°': '18-0022995'}
{'Expedien N°': '18-0022995'}
{'Expedien': '1-21-212-16-26'}
{'Reference' : 'RE9833'}
```

etc etc.

Comment: Try https://ideone.com/tAVzIi, see [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zsB5xC/1).

Comment: Awesome. thanks man. But how did you build this. Can you please give me some resources so that I can build similar regex.

Comment: Yes please. Waiting for the explanation

Comment: Finally, I can comment here. I forked this because based on your expected output, you seem to be ignoring "tramite." I wanted to know of a reliable way to actually do that without producing a flawed overlap so @WiktorStribiżew could I ask for your help in that? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55109460/python-regexforking-capture-groups-based-on-terms-but-skipping-if-another-te

Comment: For a string like ' text  Expedien N0 18-00232995' it's giving output as ('Expedien', 'N0') whereas it should be coming as ('Expedien N0', '18-00232995'). Also, I have added 'Expedien N0' to the the my_list variable. How to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
(?<!\w)(your|escaped|keywords|here)\W*([A-Z]*\d+(?:-+[A-Z]*\d+)*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zsB5xC/1).

**Pattern details**

- `(?<!\w)` - left word boundary (unambiguous, `\b` meaning is context dependent and if the next char is a non-word char, it will require a word char on the left, and that is not something users usually expect)
- `(your|escaped|keywords|here)` - Capturing group 1: your list of keywords, it can be easily built using `'|'.join(map(re.escape,my_list))` (note `re.escape` is necessary to escape special regex metacharacters like `.`, `+`, `(`, `[`, etc.)
- `\W*` - 0+ non-word chars (chars other than letters, digits or `_`)
- `([A-Z]*\d+(?:-+[A-Z]*\d+)*)` - Capturing group 2:

  - `[A-Z]*` - zero or more uppercase ASCII letters
  - `\d+` - 1 or more digits
  - `(?:-+[A-Z]*\d+)*` - 0 or more repetitions of

    - `-+` - one or more hyphens
    - `[A-Z]*\d+` - zero or more uppercase ASCII letters, 1 or more digits

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/tAVzIi):

```
import re
s="""your_text_here"""
my_list = ['Ref.:', 'Reference', 'tramite', 'Expediente', 'Expediente No', 'Expedien N°', 'Exp.No', 'Expedien']
rx = r'(?<!\w)({})\W*([A-Z]*\d+(?:-+[A-Z]*\d+)*)'.format('|'.join(map(re.escape,my_list)))
print(re.findall(rx, s))
```

Output:

```
[('Expedien', '1-21-212-16-26'), ('Reference', 'RE9833'), ('tramite', '1234567'), ('Expedien N°', '18-00777'), ('Expedien N°', '18-0022995')]
```

Answer (score 1):

**There really needs to be something that allows users with less than 50+ rep points to comment, because this thread is one I'm really curious about and want to fork off of, but didn't want to have to give a full fledged answer on, because the answer I'm giving involves finite situations and isn't flexible.**

**@Wiktor Stribiżew**

Your solution misses the "Ref." portion of the output based on your demo. It looks like he wants to skip "tramite"

**@checkmate**

In your desired output you need to edit it because "UV1234" does't show up anywhere in the string you posted

.

Anyway, I found a solution but am really hoping someone can improve upon this.

```
>>> import re

>>> string = '''some text before Expedien: 1-21-212-16-26 some random text
Reference RE9833 of all sentences.
abc
123
456
something blah blah Ref.: 
tramite  1234567
Ref.:
some junk Expedien N° 18-00777 # some new content
some text Expedien N°18-0022995 # some garbled content'''

>>> re.findall('(?:(Expedien[\s]+N\S|Ref\.(?!:[\S\s]{,11}Expedien)|Reference|Expedien))[\S\s]*?([A-Z\-]*(?:[\d]+)[\S]*)', string)

[('Expedien', '1-21-212-16-26'), ('Reference', 'RE9833'), ('Ref.', '1234567'), ('Expedien N\xb0', '18-00777'), ('Expedien N\xb0', '18-0022995')]
```

The Flaws:

- To capture correctly it relies in part on "Ref.(?!:[\S\s]{,11}Expedien)"
- First of all that "11" needs to be edited to account for other lengths of info that may be present so it is not flexible
- Secondly, if it is instead followed by "Reference" as opposed to then the third "Ref." will be captured incorrectly